# What is the purpose of the `repository` field in dependency declarations within `Ballerina.toml`?

Tags: dependencies, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

When specifying dependencies in `Ballerina.toml`, what value should be set for the `repository` element to fetch dependencies from Ballerina Central? For clarity, consider the example below

```
[[dependency]]
org = "ballerinax"
name = "googleapis.gmail"
version = "2.1.1"
repository = "local"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ballerina, the `repository` element in `Ballerina.toml` is used to specify where to fetch dependencies. When configuring dependencies, if a package is marked with `repository = "local"`, it indicates that only the packages in the local repository (specified in the dependencies section of Ballerina.toml) should be considered for the current package.

For all other packages not explicitly labeled as `repository = "local"`, Ballerina will look for them in the central repository. These dependencies are stored in the `./.ballerina` folder locally. If a required package is not found locally, Ballerina will automatically fetch it from Ballerina Central and save it in the local repository.

To resolve a package from Ballerina Central, you can add an import statement in your .bal file, like the example below:

```
import ballerinax/twitter;
```

Following this, you can either execute the command `bal pull <package-org>/<package-name>:<version> --repository <repository-id>`  or use the `bal build` command. This process ensures that the necessary dependencies are fetched from Ballerina Central and included in your project.